# Cyclic groups and abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

**Why abelian group of order 30 is always cyclic?** I know that in a group of order 30 either subgroup of order 3 or subgroup of order 5 is normal

Answer (score 4):

Since the group is abelian it's the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

$G=C_2×C_3×C_5\cong C_{30}$.

---

By the same argument,  an abelian group of order $p_1p_2\cdots p_k$, a product of distinct primes is cyclic.

Note that the isomorphism on the right is guaranteed by the Chinese remainder theorem.

You could also use the structure theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$G$ abelian group of order $30$ .

$2, 3,5$ are prime divisors of $30$ , hence (by Cauchy's theorem) $G$ has elements $a, b, c$ of orders $2, 3,5$ respectively.

Then  $g=abc$ has order $30$ ,hence $G=\langle g\rangle$

Comment: Perhaps it worths saying where abelianiness comes in.

Comment: 1)  Cauchy's theorem for finite abelian group ( infact it is true for any finite group due to Sylow)              $\quad$  2)Second times commutativity help to compute order of the product.

Comment: Thank you sir...i got it

Answer (score 0):

That comes from the abelian representation theorem. Since $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ , the unique possible torsion coefficients is $(30) $, that means that all Abelian groups of order $30$ are $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ up to isomorphism